# Undefined variable: request - Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have include this on top of my file

`use Request;`

and also,

`use Illuminate\Http\Request;`

---

When I tried use

```
$files = $request->file('images');
dd($files);
```

I kept getting

> ErrorException in PortfolioController.php line 113:
>   Undefined variable: request

**Why ?**

According to the doc of 5.1

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/requests

> use Illuminate\Http\Request;

should be enough.

---

## Controller

```
public function update($id) {

    $files = $request->file('images');

    ...

}
```

Comment: show controller function, it should have `$request` variable injected.

Comment: try Request::file('images) or inject the $request variale into your function call.

Comment: inject $request like this `public function update(Request $request, $id) { ... } `

Comment: @Webinion : Ahh got it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just remove `use Request;`
In action of your controller you should use the request as parameter:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PortfolioController extends Controller {

    public function update(Request $request, $id) {
        $files = $request->file('images');

        dd($files, $id);
        // the rest of your code
    }
}
```

Comment: mine is an update function, not index, it has parameter `$id` in there.

Comment: @kyo I added an id! hope it helped!

Comment: When I update the params as you suggested, I got this : https://i.imgur.com/M9y5GTD.png

Comment: Are you sure, `public function update(Request $request, $id) {` is correct ? ``

Comment: @kyo it is correct. You may also change the arguments in the order `update($id, Request $request)` so it looks clearer.

Comment: @kyo it seems that you have completely another problem in your exception handler. Did you change Exceptions/Handler.php file?